# glucylinder doesn't work if I use texture for a background

Tags: opengl, textures

I have a scene with lots of lines, triangles and quads, and some cylinders (glucylinder). Everything works perfectly.
I've created a texture for a background (a picture). So I can draw lines, triangles and quads exactly the same on the background. I move and rotate them without any problem. BUT the cylinders do not appear any more until I deactivate the background.
I've tried to disable everything about textures, but I have had no success at all.

Comment: You should add your code to the question using the `edit` button. Also, are you receiving any error logs?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I found the error: I used PushMatrix and PopMatrix when drawing my cylinders.
But, with the new background, I modified the MatrixMode, so the cylinders were draw out of the screen.
Now, before PushMatrix I fix MatrixMode and everything is OK